# Optimisation of loops containing conditionals with expensive math functions

Tags: c, loops, optimization, conditional-statements

I have a loop like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) schedule(static)
for (int i = 0; i < ndata; i++) {
    result[i] = calculate(data[i]);
}
```

with (a simplified version of) the function calculate() being:

```
double calculate(double in) {
    if (in < LP) {
        out = c.b1 * in;
    } else if (in < SP) {
        out = c.a2 + c.b2 * pow((c.c2 + c.d2 * in), c.e2);
    } else if (in < HP) {
        out = c.a3 + c.b3 * pow((c.c3 + c.d3 * in), c.e3);
    } else {
        out = c.a4 + c.b4 * in;
    }
    return out;
}
```

All calculation variables are double.
It's an image processing routine so ndata can be 3 x number of pixels, or for modern cameras ~1E8, and I'm trying to make the routine as responsive as possible. The calculation needed is either simple addition / multiplication or a more expensive call to pow(), depending on the subpixel value being processed. I've already done a lot of precalculation outside the loop and I'm using OpenMP to handle parallelising of the loop, but is there anything more I can do to optimise this? I'm guessing it won't auto-vectorise particularly well given that for n successive passes round the loop you might have a mix of pow() and simple calculations.

Comment: Why do you use double-precision for an imagine processing. Simple precision is generally far enough for this domain. Additionally, what is `c`? Are `c.e2` and `c.e3` compile time constant, runtime constant, a constant for the loop or a variable for the loop? Same for `LP`, `SP` and `HP`. Not to mention `out` is not even declared (unknown type and scope). Please provide a minimal reproducible example (or at least more reproducible).

Comment: What fraction of the calls hit the `pow()` paths?  Is `c` constant for all `i`, and do we know any restrictions on the values in `c`, for example if `c.e2` is always a power of 2 that would be great to know.

Comment: Given a vectorized `pow`, this could be vectorized as `out = a + b * pow((c + d*in), e)` where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are selected based on the comparisons of `in` with `LP`, `SP`, and `HP`. (E.g., for the last case, `a` is zero, `b` is one, `c` is `c.a4`, `d` is `c.b4`, and `e` is one.)

Comment: OK... Single precision could be an option. This is a contribution to a program, not my own program, and most of the other computations use double precision. If single precision produces a worthwhile speedup then I can ask about changing it. c. is a struct containing double precision variables, they are calculated out of loop as they are just parameters of the calculation that are the same for all pixels in the image. Same for LP, SP and HP, they are just parameters of the calculation and are set elsewhere. I'll edit my question to indicate that with some pseudocode.

Comment: The fraction of calls following pow() varies. In a lot of use cases LP is zero or close to it and HP is 1 or close to it, so the vast majority will follow those paths, split somewhat evenly between the two pow() calculations. However there are also use cases where HP may be set quite low and much more of the pixels will follow that code path. It would be possible to tell beforehand what proportion of pixels follow what code paths, at the cost of a pass through the image (but might be worth it as this calculation is typically repeated many times for the image as the user tweaks parameters).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I could certainly do that. The project is mainly targeted at Windows and Linux - do you know if the GNU and Microsoft math libraries vectorise where possible, or would I need to write my own vectorised pow()? (There's another similar bit of code with exp() functions instead of pow(), so the same question applies to exp... Thanks!

Comment: @JérômeRichard in an update to my previous comment, some work had already been done to change code within the project from double to single precision. It did make a difference for some calculations. I suspect it won't in this case, but before committing to the change I'd have to run the same calculations on some test images at both double and single precision, and diff the results to see whether there's any significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using arrays in your struct instead of name-numbered members. That will allow you to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ndata; i++){
  size_t j = 0;
  j += (data[i] >= LP);
  j += (data[i] >= SP);
  j += (data[i] >= HP);
  result[i] = c.a[j] + c.b[j] * 
  pow((c.c[j] + c.d[j] * data[i]), c.e[j]);
}
```

Then just populate those arrays with 0.0f and 1.0f as appropriate to make the function work.

From there it's just a matter of optimizing a specialized `pow` function for inlining and vectorization. As a bonus this should operate in constant time as long as your pow function does but at the cost of possibly unnecessary calculations for a good portion of the data - whether it's worth it or not will depend on the data set.

Comment: Thanks. I think this together with the suggestions in the comments to my original question has given me enough to go on, so I'll mark the answer as accepted.